# Making ListView Items Clickable Trouble

Tags: java, android, mysql, listview, android-listview

My Listview gets information saved on a local database and displays the information.  I am having altering what happens when my listview items are clicked.  I want to delete them, can anybody assist me with this matter, while using my code?  Thank you in Advance!

```
public class Notepad extends ListActivity {
    public static final int INSERT_ID = Menu.FIRST;
    EditText notes;
    Button add;
    ListView lv;
    String currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(
            new Date());

    private NotesDbAdapter mDbHelper;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.notepad_list);
        mDbHelper = new NotesDbAdapter(this);
        mDbHelper.open();
        fillData();
        Button add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addNote);
        // ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                createNote();

            }
        });
        // lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        //
        // public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        // int position, long id) {
        // // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
        //
        // try {
        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
        // ((TextView) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
        // .show();
        //
        // } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error",
        // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // }
        //
        // };
        //
        // });
    }

    private void createNote() {
        EditText notes = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.note);
        String noteName = notes.getText().toString();
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int seconds = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        int minutes = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR);
        mDbHelper.createNote(noteName + " Entered at " + hour + ":" + minutes
                + ":" + seconds, "");

        fillData();
    }

    private void fillData() {
        // Get all of the notes from the database and create the item list
        Cursor c = mDbHelper.fetchAllNotes();
        startManagingCursor(c);

        String[] from = new String[] { NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE };
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.text1 };

        // Now create an array adapter and set it to display using our row
        SimpleCursorAdapter notes = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                R.layout.notes_row, c, from, to);
        setListAdapter(notes);
    }
}
```

My ListView:

```
   <ListView
        android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="402dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/note" >
    </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I do in my Apps, is override the `SimpleCursorAdapter.setViewBinder()` to set the Tag of Views inside the ListView with the ID (_ID) from the DB and delete this ID from the DB in the `setOnItemClickListener()` and refresh the Adapter. Something like this:

```
        SimpleCursorAdapter notes = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
                R.layout.notes_row, c, from, to); 

    notes.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() { 

public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int column) 
{ 
TextView tv = (TextView) view; 
view.setTag=cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex ("_id")); // You need to include the _id in the query
tv.setText(String.Valueof(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex (NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE ))));
return true; 
} 
});

         lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() { 

         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
         int position, long id) { 

         TextView tv=(TextView) view;
     String ID=view.getTag();
    // Delete ID from the DB
    notes.notifyDataSetChanged(); 

         }; 

         });    
    setListAdapter(notes); 


    } 
}
```

Comment: I am not sure i know what you mean

Comment: What I understand from your question is that you want to delete the item clicked in the ListView. The problem is that you cannot link from the ListView back to the DB. This is what my answer does. Each item in the DB has _id and the viewBinder (which initially fills the LV from the DB) sets the Tag of each item (R.id.text1 in your question) in the LV to this _id. When you click the item, the listener uses the Tag of the item (set earlier) to reference the DB, delete this row from the DB and then you refresh the LV to get the new data without the clicked item

Comment: Okay thanks, i understand that completely, Sorry.  but as of right now I am stonewalled at accessing my listview items when clicked.  I am not sure how to access my list, in my xml.

Comment: It is the `view` item in the `OnItemClickListener()`. You need to cast it as a TextView (`TextView tv=(TextView) view;`)

Comment: The Adapter creates a copy of you TextView (R.id.text1) and the adapter sets its text to the values from the row NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE for each entry in the DB. This is why you need to do what I mentioned in my answer to differentiate between them and link back to the DB

Comment: Do you think you can give me a code snippet of what I should do?

Comment: Check my answer after I added an example of what you should do

Answer (score 1):

`onListItemClick` you Got Position and `Remove` it from Dynamic Array (Vector or List) Like `vector.remove(position);`.if you want to remove it from Database ,Also remove from Database.After this  You just write .....

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: My problem is i dont know how to access the list item, i get a null pointer exception, then i can try that piece of code you gave me.

Comment: i get a null pointer exception on the listview code that i commented out. Ill post logcat

Comment: lv = (ListView)findviewById(R.id.list);

Comment: I posted my Listview, how would i implement that code using my listview Id?

Answer (score 0):

You an add an onItemClickListener on your ListView just as you added on the button.
If they click an item you delete that item in the local database using an sql query. I assume since you can select data you can delete it using SQL.

After that just reinitialize the list.

That's the easiest way:)

Although I think you could better use a longpress then a normal press.
Just that items won't be deleted by accident

Comment: The thing is when i add the listener i get a null pointer exception.  I havent been able to find a way around it.